# Material-UI TextField adornedEnd right padding problem

Tags: material-ui, textfield

Using Material-UI 4.5.2. I'm adding an end adornment and want to change the right padding so that the icon would be in a right most position. I tried to override it with classes property but couldn't make it. https://codesandbox.io/s/textfield-adornedend-wf5p8

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide adornedEnd class rule to InputProps:

```
  InputProps={{
    endAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position="end">
        <IconButton disableRipple={true} size="small">
          <ClearIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </InputAdornment>
    ),
    classes: {
      adornedEnd: classes.endAdornment
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]